# AngularJS function that returns a named function

Tags: angularjs, anonymous-function

Below is some example code I obtained when trying to learn more about services in Angular. It is not the service aspect that I am confused about, rather it is function that makes up the service. The function returns `startMonitoring: function(){...}`. I have never seen this before and I am wondering how this is used. Is `startMonitoring` the name of the function? Is the function executed when the containing function returns? Is there a name for this type of return?

```
batchModule.factory('routeTemplateMonitor', ['$route', 'batchLog', '$rootScope',
  function($route, batchLog, $rootScope) {
    return {
      startMonitoring: function() {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
          batchLog($route.current ? $route.current.template : null);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Sample code at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services where it discusses services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory create an object with a function name `startMonitoring` and is executed when your calling the function.

So to use it :

```
monitor.startMonitoring();
```

In this page [Working with object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) at the **Using the Object.create method** section you will see an explanation.

Hope it's help!

Edit : The return type is just a normal javascript object

Comment: Does startMonitoring get executed when the routeTemplateMonitor service is instantiated?

Comment: @webworm : nope. Only the javascript object is instantiated. From your C# background ->  Is equal to have a class with many methods and creating a new instance. None of the method is executed while constructing object .

Comment: So if I understand correctly in your example `monitor` is the instance of the `routeTemplateMonitor` service I pass into a controller as a dependency and I would need to call the method `startMonitoring()` to execute it within the controller?

Answer (score 1):

It's an [anonymous function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)) attached as value to a property of an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Can be written as:

```
batchModule.factory('routeTemplateMonitor', ['$route', 'batchLog', '$rootScope',
   function($route, batchLog, $rootScope) {
       function startMonitoring() {
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
              batchLog($route.current ? $route.current.template : null);
           });
       }
       var service = { startMonitoring: startMonitoring };
       return service;
   };
]);
```

The function should only be invoked once in a run block:

```
app.run(['routeTemplateMonitor', function(routeTemplateMonitor) {
     routeTemplateMonitor.startMonitoring();
}]);
```

Calling it from controllers risks memory leaks from multiple calls as controllers are created and destroyed by directives such as `ng-view`, `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, etc.

---

### Starting the Monitor automatically

Alternately the monitor can be automatically started when the factory is instantiated:

```
batchModule.factory('routeTemplateMonitor', ['$route', 'batchLog', '$rootScope',
   function($route, batchLog, $rootScope) {
       function startMonitoring() {
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
              batchLog($route.current ? $route.current.template : null);
           });
       }
       var service = { anotherMethod: method };
       startMonitoring();
       return service;
   };
]);
```

```
app.run(['routeTemplateMonitor', function(routeTemplateMonitor) {
     console.log("Route Template Monitor Started");
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the name of the expression and the link!